# SignalR "server" await to SignalR Client

Tags: c#, signalr

I am currently building a .NET Core WebAPI with a SignalR hub that is sending requests to one or more SignalR clients.

At this point, I need to send a request to a SignalR client and wait for it to return the information, but wait within the same method that sent the request to the client, something like this:

```cs
public async Task<MyObject> GetItemStock() {
    await _myHubSignalR.Clients.Client(connectionId).SendAsync("MethodMessage", "ItemStockByItemId-001|pendingProcessId=34243243242342");
    // ^ I want await here until received the stock of itemId 001
}
```

The only way I found (and there must be a gap in my understanding, hence asking for your help) is something like this:

- The hub sends an order to the customer;
- The SignalR client, when receiving a post, makes a different method call;
- I define a maximum waiting time in the WebApi method;
- Within this method, I am constantly querying the database to see if it has new information.

However, I think the way I managed to get around is not good.

```cs
public async Task<MyObject> GetItemStock() {
    await _myHubSignalR.Clients.Client(connectionId).SendAsync("MethodMessage", "ItemStockByItemId-001|pendingProcessId=34243243242342");
            
    int awaitSeconds = 20000;
    int maxWait = 0;
    bool continueAwait = true;
    string result = "";
    while (continueAwait) {
            maxWait += 3000;
            Thread.Sleep(3000);
            result = await Task.Run(() => {
                return myProvider.SeeHasNewDataOnDataBase(pendingProcessId);
            });

        if (result != "" || maxWait > awaitSeconds) {
            myProvider.DeletePreviusDataFromDataBase(pendingProcessId);
            return result;
        }
    }
```

The idea was to use the method that sends the request to the SignalR client, and in this same method obtain the information that the SignalR client sent or will send.

Comment: `I need to send a request to a ClientSignalR and wait for it to return the information`...that's not how SignalR/websockets works. You can send a message to the client. Then you must end your method. When the client sends a response back, you process that as a separate method. if you need to preserve the state in between, you must store it somewhere.

Comment: It's not clear what the use case is here, but consider your architecture. If you have an API which receives a request, and must then pass that request on to something else, you need a reliable way of getting an instant response. SignalR isn't designed for that. Another API request to wherever you need this information from would make more sense.

Comment: You refer to it a lot, but `ClientSignalR` isn't an official class. Is that your own type?

Comment: @ConnorLow "ClientSignalR" is an ERP (native Windows Desktop).

Comment: Do you have a link?

Comment: @ConnorLow My client are using this software ERP (https://www.xdsoftware.pt/)

Comment: Do you have a link to documentation about ClientSignalR? I don't think that's a standard library, so if you are using a type called `ClientSignlarR`, it's probably custom.

Comment: @ConnorLow My implementation is like this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/dotnet-client?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio

So, when this client received a message, i want search for something and send back to my API. Thanks

Comment: Ok so, as I said right back in the first comments 2 weeks ago, you need to send a message to the client, then end your method. Then the client can send something back separately, as a new message to the server. The SignalR server can then process it. If you include some information which links it to the earlier message (e.g. some unique ID or something) then perhaps it's easier for the server to know what to do with it. But your API method can't just sit there waiting. Nothing that's been said here since then changes that basic reality. Have you tried to do anything to fix your code?

Comment: @ADyson It's a good ideia and i'm going try like you suggest! Thanks!